# Remove the tag synonym of [future] -> [promise]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

Recently<sup>1</sup>, [future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/future) has been made into an automatically-renamed alias of [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise). Promises are **not** futures ([in general](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/207136/160813), [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821051/155423), [in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)), so this alias is incorrect.

Rust uses the term [future](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html) to describe a fundamental asynchronous programming building block and does not use the term "promise". With this change, posters who use "future" as a tag will be rewritten to "promise". As far as I know, those questions won't show up for the keyword "future" in search engines, reducing the usefulness of search results and leading to needless duplicates.

Can this synonym or automatic renaming be reverted? If the alias is *truly needed*, perhaps someone (that isn't me) will rewrite all the Rust-related tags to something unique like `rust-future` before recreating the alias?

---

**1** — Sometime between 2021-02-08 and 2021-02-15, [based on tags I've seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZmRM.png). The [tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active) shows that the number of renames is very low:

[image: tag synonym page showing the alias of future to promise with seven renames]

Comment: According to the [Tag Synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active) page, this synonym was created in March 2014, assuming the "Create Date" is the date the synonym was created, and not the date the "future" tag was created.

Comment: It's not just Rust, they are different concepts. A Future is a low level mechanism (e.g. in Rust and Scala), while a Promise is a higher level abstraction.

Comment: Further investigation leads me to think the that Create Date is the date the synonym was _proposed_. The approval of the synonym can take years, so this may have just recently been approved. I have yet to find where one can view the history of a synonym proposal.

Comment: That's correct: the date given is the date when the synonym was proposed, not when it was approved. I have no idea how to find the date when it was approved. Automatic renaming has *always* been turned on; synonyms (when they exist) are always converted into the "primary" tag automatically. The fact that there's only been 7 renames suggests that the synonym hasn't been active for very long. The tags haven't been merged, so I can trivially remove the synonym. Which I will, since I find your arguments compelling.